# Eclipse doesn't open Android xml files and raising Nullpointer exception

Tags: xml, eclipse, adt

I have problem in android xml files, when i open my android xml file, it shows an ***java.lang.NullpointerException*** as alert and plugin error, PluginPath:***com.android.ide.ecllipse.adt***.i was updated API-19 at yesterday,then only have this problem. Kindly Help me, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go to Help and update your eclipse and your Android SDK from SDK manager. If you don't want that you can install a new version of Eclipse.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq?hl=sv-SE&csw=1#wstinstallerror